# Diagonalizable matrix and Zariski topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-curves

Identify  the  set  of   square  matrices  of  order  two defined   over  $ \mathbb{C}$   with  the   affine  space $A^4$.  What  can  you  tell   about   the set   of diagonalisable matrices?  I  noticed  that  it   corresponds
   to  a union  of an open   Zariski   set   and   a  closed  Zariski   set.  It  is  this  set  open  or   closed?

Comment: I'd say it is neither. Certainly not closed.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli How  can  I   prove  that?

Comment: It is not closed because it's interior is non-empty and not all matrices are diagonalisable. For (Zariski) open, let's see...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is neither.

- Since it contains a non-empty Zariski open set (for instance, the set of matrices with $n$ dinstinct eigenvalues), it is dense in $\Bbb A^4$, but not all matrices are diagonalisable.
- The set of non-diagonalisable matrices is not Zariski closed, because it isn't euclidean-closed. For instance $$\begin{pmatrix}1&\varepsilon&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{\varepsilon\to0}\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: can you explain each one of the assertions?

Comment: What are you unfamiliar with?

Comment: Why the set of diagonalisable matrices is dense in $\mathbb{A^4}$?

Comment: Sorry, I understood that par

Comment: I have a question. Why the set isn't open? By your explanation I understand that the set of diagonalisable matrices couldn't be dense in $\mathbb{A^4}$. The  proof of this fact is obviously?

Comment: Open Zariski sets are euclidean-open and closed Zariski sets are euclidean closed. I gave you an example of a sequence of non-diagonalisable matrices which converge, in the euclidean metric, to a diagonalisable matrix. Hence, the set of non-diagonalisable matrices is not euclidean closed. So it is not Zariski closed. Therefore, its complementary is not Zariski open. The set of diagonalisable matrices **is** dense in $\Bbb A^4$ (both euclidean and Zariski) because it contians a nonempty open Zariski set (and, in fact, I said it).

Comment: Thank you for the above details. Now, I understand why the  diagonalisable matrices is not a Zariski closed set. And why it can't  be open?

Comment: If the set of diagonalisable matrices is Zariski open then is complementary is Zariski closed. Then the set of matrices which are not diagonalisable is also closed in Euclidian topology. But I can find a sequence of matrices which are not diagonalisable, but converges at a diagonalisable matrix, contradiction. It is correct my argument?

Comment: That's what I wrote, just said backwards.